# IIS Express is removing file extension Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm developing a web application project using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET Framework 4.5. Wen I run my project in debug mode (F5) it starts IIS Express 10.0 but I'm geting a 404 error message because the file extension is always removed. It should be `http://localhost:56996/default.aspx` but is `http://localhost:56996/default`.

When I publish my project on IIS the problem does not exist.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create a new project using the default template and try again? I don't think it is an issue of VS but your project itself.

Comment: Lex Li, I think it's something with my browser because when I executed my project in Google Chrome, the issue has occurred but when I executed it with Edge, the issue doesn't have occurred.